# Problems with getting data from a class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I guess this is quite basic, but I am struggling with getting data (in this case a simple string) from a class.

My class is quite simple; it looks like this:

```
    @interface myBook : NSObject {

    NSString *titleName;
    NSString *titleColour;

}
```

And then I have all the @property and @synthesise calls. I import this (#import myBook.h) in my viewController, where I want to add books to my library. So I have this set of variables to control my library:

```
    NSMutableArray *myLibrary;
NSUInteger currentBookNumber;
myBook *currentBook;
```

and:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myLibrary;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger currentBookNumber;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NoteBook *currentBook;
```

I then set up my library like so:

```
-(void) setupLibrary {

myBook *newBook = [[myBook alloc] init];

newBook.titleName = @"Test";
newBook.titleColour = @"orange";

[myLibrary addObject:newBook];
[myLibrary addObject:newBook];
[myLibrary addObject:newBook];

currentBookNumber = 0;
```

}

In order to get data from the current book I have the following method:

```
-(NmyBook *) currentBook {


myBook *thisBk = [self.myLibrary
                        objectAtIndex:self.currentBookNumber];
return thisBk;
```

}

Now my problem is that if I want to get data from myLibrary and call this in my viewDidLoad, I will only get nil for the title... where did I go wrong?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[self setupLibrary];
NSLog(@"TitleName:%@", currentBook.titleName);
```

Comment: Did the answers help? Please select the answer that was correct... If not, please comment to let us know how it was not helpful. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues I see:

Number 1:
I hope the currentBook method return type is a typo. I'm seeing a -(NmyBook *)... shouldn't that be a - (myBook *)?

Number 2:
You never initialized the currentBook object. Before you call the NSLog, you should go

```
currentBook = [self currentBook];
```

Where [self currentBook] calls the currentBook method and sets the returned object as the currentBook object.

Finally, try not having the same names for variables and methods :)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `self.currentBook.titleName`. `currentBook.titleName` won't trigger your accessor.

By the way, your `setupLibrary` is leaking. You'll want to add `[newBook release]` after the last `[myLibrary addObject:newBook]` call.

Answer (score 1):

You had called one property currentBook and one method currentBook :
Normally it works but you should call the method getCurrentBook;

and the right to access to a property in his class is to use :

```
[self.theProperty method];
```

Use :

```
newBook.titleName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test"];
newBook.titleColor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Orange"];
```

After you can call :

```
NSLog(@"TitleName:%@", self.currentBook.titleName);
```